# Leaflet tiles stay grey

Tags: leaflet, tile

Since one day i have problems on my website to access leaflet. At some zoom levels the map or some tiles just stays grey.

http://www.citizen-science.at/bkroadkill/roadkill-2014-05-06-0826/

Zoom out to make it work again.

I think I found a problem:

[image]

Is this because the maximum number of requests is reached? Or did I fail somewhere else (it was working for about 2 month now).

Comment: works for me.  maybe you're experiencing connectivity issues...?

Comment: The map in that link is a Google map.

Comment: The map is working for me. As for the error, CloudMade revoked their API keys for non-enterprise accounts on May 1: http://support.cloudmade.com/answers/enterprise_plans If you were using CloudMade before, maybe try refreshing your cache to remove any tiles you had cached?